# Difference between Clear and Remove in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, the documentation for [ClearAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearAll.html) states:

> `ClearAll[symb1, symb2, ...]`
>   clears values, definitions, attributes, messages, and defaults with symbols.

It also supports a similar format where it can clear any values / definitions which match an input string pattern:

```
ClearAll["form1", "form2", ...]
```

But there's also the function [Remove](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Remove.html), for which the documentation says:

> `Remove[symbol1, ...]`
>   removes symbols completely, so that their names are no longer recognized by Mathematica.

It also supports the same pattern based string input that `ClearAll` supports.

To me, it seems like both functions accomplish the same exact thing. Is there any practical difference to using one or the other?

I know that if I give an attribute to a symbol, `Clear` won't remove it but `ClearAll` and `Remove` will. But it seems like `Remove` and `ClearAll` are doing the same thing.

Comment: This recent Mathgroup thread seems relevant: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3db59462237f509f. Look particularly at the third post of Oleksandr Rasputinov in that thread (it is 15-th from the beginning of the thread) - he gives some good reasons for when `Remove` might be needed and what makes it special.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ClearAll` leaves the symbol in the symbol table:

```
In[1]:= x=7;

In[2]:= ?x
Global`x

x = 7

In[3]:= ClearAll[x]

In[4]:= ?x
Global`x
```

`Remove` removes it from the symbol table:

```
In[5]:= Remove[x]

In[6]:= ?x

Information::notfound: Symbol x not found.
```

One reason to use `Remove` instead of `ClearAll` is if a symbol hides another symbol further down your $ContextPath. Here's a contrived example:

```
In[1]:= $ContextPath = { "Global`", "System`" };

In[2]:= Global`Sin[x_] := "hello" 

Sin::shdw: Symbol Sin appears in multiple contexts {Global`, System`}
    ; definitions in context Global`
     may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

In[3]:= Sin[1.0]

Out[3]= hello

In[4]:= ClearAll[Sin]

In[5]:= Sin[1.0]

Out[5]= Sin[1.]

In[6]:= Remove[Sin]

In[7]:= Sin[1.0]

Out[7]= 0.841471
```

Another reason to use `Remove` is that the notebook interface only includes known symbols when you choose Edit > Complete Selection (or on a Mac, press Command-K).

Comment: Interesting. Is there any realistic cases where you might actually have to remove something from the symbol table?

Comment: A common case occurs if one forgets to load a package before using a contained function -- for example evaluating `JavaClassPath[]` prior to calling ``Needs["JLink`"]``.  If the requisite `Needs` is called afterwards, you end up with ``JLink`JavaClassPath`` shadowing ``Global`JavaClassPath``, with the front-end showing both symbols in red.  ``Remove[Global`JavaClassPath]`` fixes the situation.

Comment: @WReach: That actually explains and solves a problem I've been wondering about for ages.

Comment: @robmayoff You could note that for non-mac computers use the command shortcut `CTRL+k`, and doing so is much faster than using the menu ;).

Comment: @Mike An example to show why `Clear(All)[]` doesn't remove symbols: `x := y; Clear[y]`, `?x` shows that `y` is still referenced.  After `Remove[y]` any existing references will be replaced with `Removed["y"]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually `Removed` is not a normal head, but rather a print form. And once we `Remove` the `y`, we invalidate `x` in a subtle but permanent way - reintroducing the `y` into the session won't help. `Remove` is really a rather special-purpose destructuve operation, aimed more at removing auto-generated symbols. In a system of inter-connected functions (possibly from different packages), for this reason `Remove` is safe only if nothing depends on the symbol being removed. Resolving shadowing is the only mainstream (frequent, non-advanced) application of `Remove` I am aware of.

Comment: @Leonid I was not aware of `Removed` being special

Comment: @Szabolcs Just saw your comment: this, among many other things, I learned from the book of David Wagner (page 251). In particular, he argues that while the removed symbol is printed (and has a `FullForm`) as `Removed["sym"]`, applying `Head` to it yields `Symbol`. For code like this: `Clear[b];b := a;Remove[a];b`, you can not, e.g., "resurrect" `a` in `b` with this: `b /. Removed[x_] :> ToExpression[x]`, but, since `Removed["a"]` represents a symbol marked for removal, this will work: `b /. Cases[b, s_Symbol :> (s :> a), {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]`. I find this little detail interesting.

Comment: @Leonid Yes, that's true, and also operations like `Map`/`Apply`/etc. don't work on `Removed` things. Another interesting thing I found recently is that expressions containing removed symbols may continue to function correctly, take e.g. `a = Module[{x=1}, x]` then `Remove[x]; a`.

Comment: @Szabolcs But in `a = Module[{x=1}, x]`, `x` evaluates to `1`, and so `a` is assigned just `1`.  Moreover, that `x` inside `Module` is `x$...`, not the top-level `x`. So, calling `Remove` on the top-level `x` has no effect either on `Module`-generated `x` (which by then has probably been removed by `Module` anyway), or `a`, which has `1` as its `OwnValue`. So, I don't see anything surprising here.

Comment: @Leonid Sorry, of course that should have been `a:=`, not `a=`. The symbol in `Module`, I think`, is `x` up to the point where the `Module` starts being evaluated.  You can verify that it gets removed by `?a`.  Also, this works with `Block` as well.  Try this: `a:=Block[{x,y=1}, Print[x];y]; Remove[x,y]; a`.  I just thought it is interesting that whatever it is that is denoted by `Removed["x"]`, it still continutes be to usable as a symbol/variable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, very interesting finding! I did not expect anything like this. Now we just have to find some cool constructuve uses of this effect :)